# Installing geopandas with docker

Tags: python, pandas, docker, geopandas

I get this error: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip, while trying to install geopandas in python. I tried multiple ways to solve it but non worked. Does anyone have a suggestion? I tried the following command: pip install --upgrade geopandas mapclassify folium, but it also gives this error: note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

I restarted the Kernel, but it still does not work. I installed geopandas using terminal, and made sure my docker container is up. It still does not work.